# How can I solve my ubuntu laptop blinking the screen?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lenovo, screen, 22.04

I got a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3i with a Nvidia GTX 1650 GPU and a Intel Core i5 CPU. I installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS and my GPU was not being identified by the system, so then I installed the *nvidia-driver-510* driver because it was listed as the recommended when I executed the *ubuntu-drivers devices* command.
My screen kept blinking. Sometimes I'm using the computer and it starts and stops. The screen gets black and then comes back multiple times. It looks something like this: https://www.loom.com/share/f941ca79f2fd4f7f8aad13324c14a4f4, but all my screen gets black.
I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Do you run on Wayland or on X? Enter `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` in a terminal to see which it is. Also try this: reboot, and at the login screen choose the other option (using the cog wheel button). Does the blinking still happen?

Comment: When entering the command it displays me *x11*.
Rebooting and selecting other user would change what?

Comment: Not another user, but another session type: the choice would be between "ubuntu" and "ubuntu on xorg" or something similar. Currently, you are running "ubuntu on xorg", so try "ubuntu", meaning Wayland.

Comment: I just saw here and it's already on "Ubuntu" and it has the option of "Ubuntu on Wayland". Should I try the other option?

Comment: Yes, try Wayland.

Comment: I changed it and nothing changed. It still kept blinking.